# JSON string values are getting saved without quotes

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have two programs.  The first program creates some JSON using Json.Net and then launches the second program, passing the JSON to it.  The second program saves the JSON to a file using the `SaveFileDialog` from WinForms.  The problem is the string values in the JSON are not saving properly.

For example, it saves

```
{
    projectName : MY_PROJECT_NAME
}
```

When it should be

```
{
    "projectName" : "MY_PROJECT_NAME"
}
```

Later when I'm trying to deserialize the JSON and convert to an object, I'm getting an error, but only with string values.

Here is the code that saves the file:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string seriaizedData = args[0];
    Stream streamData;

    SaveFileDialog savefiledialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    savefiledialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/Bamboo Wall";
    savefiledialog.Filter = "bamboo files (*.bamboo)|*.bamboo|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    savefiledialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    savefiledialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (savefiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((streamData = savefiledialog.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(seriaizedData);
            streamData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            streamData.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that creates the JSON:

```
FloorModel grdData = GridData.gridData.gridDataClassList[GetActiveTabIndex()];
//How I get the object does not matter so much
string jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grdData);
print (jsonObj);

Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "Narnia.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = jsonObj;
myProcess.Start();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you've shown isn't performing any serialization. I very much doubt that this is a JSON.NET issue. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing JSON on the command line from one program to the other.  Quote characters and spaces have special meaning to the command line parser, so you will need escape your JSON string judiciously if you want it to survive the command line parsing process intact.  Another potential issue is the command line has a length limit, depending on what platform you are running on.  So if the JSON you are trying to pass is large, it may be truncated even if you manage to escape it correctly.  In short, I don't recommend this approach.

Instead, I would make your first program write the JSON to a temporary file, then pass the path of the temp file to the second program via the command line.  That program can then copy the file to the correct location as specified by the user.

So, something like this:

**Sending Program**

```
FloorModel grdData = GridData.gridData.gridDataClassList[GetActiveTabIndex()];

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grdData);
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllText(tempFile, json);

Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "Narnia.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = '"' + tempFile + '"';
myProcess.Start();
```

**Receiving Program**

```
string jsonTempFile = args[0];

try
{
    SaveFileDialog savefiledialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    savefiledialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/Bamboo Wall";
    savefiledialog.Filter = "bamboo files (*.bamboo)|*.bamboo|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    savefiledialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    savefiledialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (savefiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File.Copy(jsonTempFile, savefiledialog.FileName, overwrite: true);
    }
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(jsonTempFile);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I don't know how many data I'll send in the command line. Yours is a much better approach.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.